# If $A = LU$ and $B = UL$, the $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> If $A = LU$ and $B = UL$, where $L$ is a unit lower triangular and $U$ is an upper triangular matrices, then $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are obtained by solving the equation: $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$. We have

$$\det(A - \lambda I) = \det(LU - \lambda I)= \det(L(U - \lambda L^{-1})) = \det(L)\det(U - \lambda L^{-1}).$$
Now, from the previous equation, we have
$$\det(L)\det(U - \lambda L^{-1}) = \det(U - \lambda L^{-1})\det(L) = \det(UL - \lambda I) = \det(B - \lambda I), $$
thus, we have
$$\det(A - \lambda I) = \det(B - \lambda I).$$
Does this means that they have the same eigenvalues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is fine, but it requires $L$ to be invertible.

In general, the eigenvalues of $AB$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $BA$ for any two square matrices $A,B$.

Comment: I think in this case $L$ is invertible, because the diagonal of $L$ are ones and is lower triangular.

Comment: Ok, I had never seen "unit"  used in that way. So, your argument is fine. But the result is still true without using "unit"  nor "triangular" .

Comment: No problem. Thank you very much, I appreciate it.